# When is $\frac{x}{a} + \frac{y}{b} > 1$ true

Tags: inequality

Let $a,\ b,\ x \text{ and } y$ be four real numbers where $a \neq 0$ and $b \neq 0$ and

$$\frac{x}{a} + \frac{y}{b} > 1$$

I have to solve this inequality for $x$ and $y$

I tried the following:

$$\frac{bx}{ab} + \frac{ay}{ab} > 1$$

$$\Leftrightarrow \frac{bx + ay}{ab} > 1$$

$$\Rightarrow bx + ay > ab$$

I got stuck here. I tried to rewrite $ab$ as a sum using the identity $\log(ab) = \log(a)  +\log(b)$ but it does not add any values toward the solution. any hints?

Comment: The first equivalence is valid regardless of signs, but the second one is valid only if $ab>0$. Since you are mentioning logarithms, you should perhaps assume that $a>0$ and $b>0$.

Comment: I think you mean you want to solve the inequality for $x$ and $y$, right?

Comment: Thanks @GeoffreyTrang for the note! I corrected it.

Comment: @ShyamalSayak exactly

Comment: @AyoubFalah Then you should edit that in your post.

Comment: @ShyamalSayak I think it is clear enough

Comment: @AyoubFalah You wrote $a$ and $y$ instead of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: What is the question?  The inequality is true, when it is true!  Is the question "given $\{x,a,b\}$, what are the conditions on $y$?  Or given any three, what is the inequality involving the fourth variable?

Answer (score 1):

The inequality is defined by a line with $x$-intercept $a$ and $y$-intercept $b$:

$$\cases{y>-\frac{b}{a}x+b & \text{if $b>0$}\\
y<-\frac{b}{a}x+b & \text{if $b<0$}}$$

So substituting any $x=\xi\in\mathbb R$ provides an interval:
$$\cases{y_\xi\in\left(\frac{b(a-\xi)}{a},\infty\right) & \text{if  $b>0$}\\
y_\xi\in\left(-\infty,\frac{b(a-\xi)}{a}\right) & \text{if  $b<0$}
}$$ such that $(x,y)=(\xi,y_\xi)$ satisfies